# Magento2: how to unhide productimage on frontend

Tags: magento2

I did an upgrade from Magento 1 > Magento2 and all seem well but the following problem occured:
On default all the images are set to HIDE and on the frontend the Magento placeholder is shown.
[image] 
Unchecking that option will show the productimage but I don't want to do it manually for severall hundreds of producs. 
Is there an easier way to unhide (i.e. phpmyadmin, programming etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 store this checkbox value in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table under column "disabled".

You may have to write some custom script to change value from 1 to 0 to unhide images.

Comment: I've checked this and they'll have value 0 already  so nothing there can be changed. I set it all to 1 and back to 0 and now it's shown. Thanks !!!
Here the SQL I've used
     UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` SET `disabled` = '0' 

maybe usefull for other people